# Defining enum maps in Spring beans

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, dependency-injection

I am trying to define an enum map in my Spring beans xml, and I want it to populate in the xml, however when I try to define it like this

```
<bean class = "java.util.EnumMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:map key-type="org.itemlist.products.stockitem">
            <entry key="stockitem.SOAP">100</entry>
        </util:map> 
    </constructor-arg>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my beans configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


    <bean class = "java.util.EnumMap">
        <constructor-arg>
            <util:map key-type="org.itemlist.products.stockitem">
                <entry key="stockitem.SOAP">100</entry>
            </util:map> 
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I add a value inside entry, this is now the error

```
cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'entry' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you define those schema in the header:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
```

And the namespace:

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

Comment: Ooops, I forgot that, but when I added it it still has an error

Answer (score 1):

You can define it like this :

```
    <bean id="springBean" class="a.b.c.d.MyEnum">
        <constructor-arg>
            <util:map key-type="a.b.c.d.MyEnum" value-type="aa.b.c.d.Mya.b.c.d.MyVal">
                <entry>
                    <key><value type="a.b.c.d.MyEnum">ENUM-VAL1</value></key>
                    <ref bean="myValBean1" />
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key><value type="a.b.c.d.MyEnum">ENUM-VAL1</value></key>
                    <ref bean="myValBean1" />
                </entry>
            </util:map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that the `entry` element must be empty, i.e. contain no text or other elements. The syntax you want is:

```
<entry key="stockitem.SOAP" value="100"/>
```

The `entry` element also lets you pass a reference to another bean as the value, e.g.:

```
<entry key="stockitem.SOAP" value-ref="myOtherBean"/>
```

(which is of no use in your situation, I just mention it for completeness)